# Can anyone tell me why these named anchors are not working in IE?

Tags: html

Hey Guys,
I can't seem ti understand why these trivial named anchors
[here](http://www.planeteclipse.com/site/pages/policies)

are not working in IE? FF, Safari and Chrome have no problem.

Comment: Which IE version? It works on my IE8.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the links at the top should jump to the relevant paragraph (e.g. "Terms of Use"), then it works for me - in IE6, IE8, and IE8 in IE7 mode.

Comment: Funny I have several PC's in the office and they did not work in IE7 or 8, mmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't, but I can tell you that the name atribute on links is deprecated now. You should assign an id to an existing element to make this more semantic. That way you don't need to have any anchors that don't have a href attribute. And who knows, it might help the IE problem!

Comment: The name attribute is NOT deprecated.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2

Comment: Okay, the method is deprecated. Based on what the # does in an href attribute of an anchor, using name negates this.

Answer (score 1):

they're not pointing to anything. you need to add `id="anchorName"` to your `<h2>`s.

Comment: They're pointing to the 'old' method of this implementation. That is, a name attribute assigned to an anchor on the page, such as <a name="warranty"></a>